# i'm not getting the correct amount of income in civilization 6

Tags: civilization-6

I was playing a regular game when randomly my nation went bankrupt. the game informed me that I'm losing more money than i'm making every turn, even though it said i was making +150 coins per turn on the UI. After disbanding a few troops, i was no longer bankrupt and my income was +200 coins per turn on The UI. however, i was only receiving 15 coins per turn. i checked and confirmed that i was in fact supposed to make 200 coins per turn, so i have no clue on why i'm making less coins.

Comment: Are you trying to say that the UI said that your gold was increasing by 200 per turn but, at the end of each turn, your gold total only increased by 15?

Comment: yes, i kept getting 15 coins per turn even though it said +200 on the UI. and when it was +150 coins per turn on the UI, i made a negative amount of money per turn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem once and finally realised it was because enemy spies were stealing my income. That is not shown on the UI, but it does remove gold from you periodically.

Try assigning counter-spies in your economic centers.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I learned that England was stealing my money.